# Updating a row in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I need to update a particular row. This doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated.

View *updated*:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create("Setting", array('action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->checkbox('blog_state');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

Controller *updated*:

```
public function index($id = 0){
    $this->Setting->id = $id;
    if (empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Setting->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->request->data['Setting']['id'] = $id;
            $this->Setting->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('This should have saved...');
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
blog_state is a boolean, and works fine. It loads the value from the DB normally and saves it to the new row normally. (I need it to update the existing row it is being pulled from, which is where my problem is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create("Setting", array('action' => 'index'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->checkbox('blog_state');
echo $this->Form->end('Save Page');
?>
```

You will also need to make sure you set the id in the function so it will populate the value correctly. The record cannot be updated unless it knows the PK ID it is updating.

The way you can accomplish this is by setting it in the request data:

```
$this->request->data['Setting']['id'] = $id;
```

Then it will automatically be set in the view.

**UPDATE**

It looks like your logic may be flawed. The form will not necessarily pass the ID back on the URL. So update you form like so and check again if it works. It looks like the way you currently have it it will set ID to null which will create a new record.

```
public function index($id = 0){
    if (empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Setting->id = $id;
        $this->request->data = $this->Setting->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Setting->save($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('This should have saved...');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed my array. The id is now properly set, but it isn't saving it. Here is the query it produces: **INSERT INTO `settings` (`blog_state`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (1, '2012-03-01 23:27:05', '2012-03-01 23:27:05')**

Comment: Check your form. It appears the the id is not being handled. Make sure it is showing up in the form.

Comment: Yeah, it shows up in the form. Updated controller and view above:

Comment: Yeah, bizarre. That updates the page to reflect the change, but in the database, it still inserts the new row...

Comment: Do a pr($this->request->data) and update the post so we can see what is being returned.

Comment: Array([Setting] => Array([id] => 0 [blog_state] => 1)) is what I am getting when I run it, using my example. I get the following when I run it using your example: Array([Setting] => Array([id] =>  [blog_state] => 1))

Comment: This shows the ID is not being set and that is why it is creating a new record instead of pulling one. You need to make sure that you are calling the function with an ID: /settings/index/{ID}

Comment: Isn't that what is happening here: function index($id = 0) ?

Comment: Yes, that set's the $id = 0. But I believe 0 is treated and empty or null. This is why it is creating a new record every time. If you want a default record and you do not plan on passing a value, set it to 1. Then the same record will be updated every time.

Comment: BINGO! I can't believe that was the problem! Agitated and relieved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to know what row it is effecting (this will usually be argument to your function).

```
public function index() {
    // Things here
}
```

This will create the index page for that controller.

Create an edit function like

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Setting->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Setting->exists()) {
        // Exception.
    }

    if ($this->Setting->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Saved'));
    }
}
```

Then you can access it like http://example.com/setting/edit/45

Comment: I know this to be correct, but is it even possible to save on the index() function? For simplicity, I didn't want to add a second function to the controller. If this is bad practice, let me know.

Comment: You can assign functions to anything really. Including index. However, index is unique in that it doesnt need "index" written into the url.

However using an edit() function follows a correct RESTful approach. It takes such a small amount of time add the edit function, I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have primary key id column in your DB if not override the your chosen primary key in model like below.

```
<?php
```

class Test extends AppModel{

```
public $primaryKey = 'primarykey column name';
```

}
?>